# R: output from for loop into vector/dataframe - object not found

Tags: r, function, for-loop, vector

I am trying to compile two vectors from my `for` loop, to then `cbind` into a table. (I was trying to do this all in one step, but because of the below issue I'm trying to simplify.)

I set three vectors, `id_name`, `count_rows`, and `id_test`.

Going through my `new_dat` (a pre-exiting data frame), I'm setting vector `result` to be the number of the rows where the ID is `i`.

I'm then printing the output, which works fine.

But when I try to push the values into the vectors, I get `Error: object 'id_name' not found`. And the same for the other two.

Here's my code:

```
id_name <- c()
count_rows <- c()
id_test <- c()

for (i in id) {
  result <- sum(new_dat$ID == i)

  id_test <- c("hello", "world")
  id_name <- c(id_name, i)
  count_rows <-c(count_rows, result)

  print(result)
  print(i)
}
```

Comment: Did you try changing the parameters inside the `for`? Perhaps`for (i in 1:length(id))` It's difficult to say what behavior is expected with no data (at least for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your vectors differently. See below; you may need to change `numeric` if your data aren't numeric, and substitute the data's actual length for `N` (if you know it beforehand).

```
id_name <- vector('numeric', length=N)
```

What you are doing now creates a `NULL` variable, of class `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks - that's helpful. I think I was also getting in tizz about the scoping of variables within functions so it was all a bit of a mess

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If so, please consider accepting my answer if that was the problem.